# Cant change tab icon on android 4.1.2

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout, android-drawable

When I try to change tab icon in 2.3 its working but not on android 4.1.2 .

```
 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("device").setIndicator("Device",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),
                    FragmentOne.class, null);
```

I can see ic_launcher icon when using on device 3.0 or lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inflated custom layout in my Tab which solved my issue -

```
TabSpec tSpecWork = mTabHost.newTabSpec("work");
        View tabIndicator   = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabimage,mTabHost.getTabWidget(),false);
        ((TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title_tab)).setText(getString(R.string.message)); 
        ((ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon_tab)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        tSpecWork.setIndicator(tabIndicator);    

        mTabHost.addTab(tSpecWork,
                FragmentOne.class, null);
```

This is my tabimage xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:padding="5dp" >

 <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/icon_tab"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title_tab"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Fragments.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/

To support in all versions,it's best to use Action bar sherlock library and implement it.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-navigation-tabs-containing-listview-to-action-bar-in-pre-honeycomb-versions-using-sherlock-library/